# visit a website with multiple domains on the same server using the IP address

Tags: webserver, www

I've a web server hosting multiple domains, user webmin and virtualmin. How can I view the website for example www.abc.com by IP address? As I remember, something like user mode of Apache can view the website by IP address in format like `123.123.123.123/~username`, but it seems not to work for my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to trick your local DNS resolver by putting IP address - server name entries into `/etc/hosts`.

Then you can access the website with the correct name because your browser sends the correct Host in the HTTP request header.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857376/send-host-header-when-accessing-ip-address-in-firefox for more options.